# Opencv RTSP streaming with ffmpeg and gstreamer

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

I am using an ip camera which has mainstream (with resolution 1920x1080) and substream (with resolution 720x576). My aim is to detect the motion by using the substream, if motion occurs I take a snopshot from the mainstream and do some processing on this image. Here is my code'

```
    VideoCapture cap;   //video capture device captures the pal stream
    VideoCapture cap2;  //video capture device captures the main stream

    // cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,1);
    // cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,1);
    //cap.set(CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_QUEUE_LENGTH,1);
    //cap2.set(CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_QUEUE_LENGTH,1);
    cap.open("rtsp://usr:pass@x.x.x.x:554/Streaming/Channels/2?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_2",CAP_FFMPEG);  //open substream
    cap2.open("rtsp:///usr:pass@x.x.x.x:554/Streaming/Channels/1?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1",CAP_FFMPEG);  //open mainstream
    bool frame_read = false;
    int motion val;

    while (true) {
        frame_read = cap.read(rgb_im); //read the frame from substream
        //cap2.grab();
        if (!frame_read) {
            break;
        }
        cvtColor(rgb_im, gray_im, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        motion_val = detect_motion(gray_im);   //find the motion value

        if (motion_val > MOTION_OCCURRED)    //check if motion occurs
        {
            cap2>>frame_big;    //get one frame from the main stream
            process(frame_big);  //do processing
        }
        imshow("1", rgb_im);
            if (waitKey(1) >= 0)
                break;
    }`
```

When, I open the stream with CAP_FFMPEG flag latency is very low (under 1 sec). As seen above I regularly read the substream and if motion occurs I read the mainstream. But the frames which I read from the mainstream is not synchronous with the substream. Most probably I grab the frames which waits in the buffer. So I miss the frame with motion and I get an older frame. How can I handle this issue? Somehow I have to make buffer size 1 frame but I cannot find any way.

I have tried 
`cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,1);` but since it needs DC1394 support it does not solve my problem.

Secondly, I have tried `cap2.grab()` after I read the substream but it increases the latency(make latency about 3 seconds).

Thirdly, I have tried to open videocapture objects with cv_cap_gstreamer flag `cap.open("rtsp://usr:pass@x.x.x.x:554/Streaming/Channels/2transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_2",CV_CAP_GSTREAMER);` . It solves my buffering problem. In other words, when I detect the motion from the substream, I am able to capture the same instant from the mainstream. But with the gstreamer I have huge delay about 3 seconds which is not desirable for my case.(with gstreamer I tried to read several rtsp streams with different resolutions and latency remains the same) How can I solve the latency issue when I am using gstreamer with opencv?

Comment: Always read from both streams, but process second stream only if motion detected in the first stream. BTW, I reckon, streams will be out of sync in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the reason why I open the substream is to make reading process quicker. Mainstream's resolution is too high and it is not necessary for doing motion detection. If I have to read mainstream regularly , I just use mainstream both for motion detection and processing.@DmitriSosnik

Comment: Reading should be cheap, processing is expensive.